# Combine two Pandas dataframes with the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with the same index but different columns. How do I combine them into one with the same index but containing all the columns?

I have:

```
  A 
1 10 
2 11

  B
1 20
2 21
```

and I need the following output:

```
  A  B
1 10 20
2 11 21
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: why use pd.concat over pd.merge?

Comment: @LiamFoley: `merge` is for join-style operations.  If you just want to concatenate DataFrames, that's what `concat` is for.

Comment: Thanks! I would write `pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis='columns')`
For a more readable version

Answer (score 20):

You've got a few options depending on how complex the dataframe is:

Option 1:

```
df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

Option 2:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```