# How to concatenate for the right side in one file all the .csv files of a directory with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, glob

I have a folder with .csv files all the files have the same ids but different contet, like this:

File one:

```
id, content
jdhfs_SDGSD_9403, bla bla bla bla
aadaaSDFDS__ASdas_asad_342, bla bla
...
asdkjASDAS_asdasSFSF_sdf, bla bla
```

File two:

```
id, content
jdhfs_SDGSD_9403, string string string
aadaaSDFDS__ASdas_asad_342, string string string
...
asdkjASDAS_asdasSFSF_sdf, string string string
```

I would like to leave the id column but merge in one new file the content, something like this(i.e. generate a new file):

```
id, content
jdhfs_SDGSD_9403, bla bla bla bla string string string
aadaaSDFDS__ASdas_asad_342, bla bla string string string
...
asdkjASDAS_asdasSFSF_sdf, bla bla string string string
```

This is what I tried:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
with open('path/file1.csv', 'w') as res, \
        open('/path/file1.csv') as f1,\
        open('path/file1.csv') as f2:
    for line1, line2 in izip_longest(f1, f2, fillvalue=""):
        res.write("{} {}".format(line1.rstrip(), line2))
```

The problem with this is that is merging everthing in one line. Any idea of how to do this in a more pythonic way?.

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.read_csv('path/file1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('path/file2.csv')    

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print new_df


new_df.to_csv('/path/new.csv')
```

Then the header was merged like this:

`,id,content,id,content`

And the content like this:

`0jdhfs_SDGSD_9403, bla bla bla bla jdhfs_SDGSD_9403, string string string`.

How can I get something like this?:

`jdhfs_SDGSD_9403, bla bla bla bla string string string`

Without the index number of the dataframe?.

Answer (score 1):

read the csvs's in using pd.read_csv(FILE)

Then do this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Or merge them (pd.merge())

See this question:

[Combine two Pandas dataframes with the same index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773683/combine-two-pandas-dataframes-with-the-same-index/28773733#comment45827623_28773733)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do pandas can generate a new file?.

Comment: @johndoe  YOURDF.to_csv('filename.csv')

Comment: Thanks for the support, any idea of how to remove the dataframe's index number from the new file?.

Comment: @johndoe look into the reset_index and set_index methods.

Comment: I tried this: `new_df = pd.concat([df1['content'], df2['content']], axis=1)

new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

new_df['content'].to_csv('path/new.csv')
` but the index number still in the new file thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`csv` standard python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

i.e.

```
import csv

with open(filename1) as file1, open(filename2) as file2, open(newname, "w") as newfile:
    csv1 = csv.reader(file1)
    csv2 = csv.reader(file2)
    newcsv = csv.writer(newfile)

    header = next(csv1)
    next(csv2) # Skip the header

    newcsv.writerow(header)

    for row1, row2 in zip(csv1, csv2):
        id, content1 = row1
        id, content2 = row2
        newcsv.writerow((id, " ".join((content1, content2))))
```

Comment: I got this:`   newcsv.write(header)
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write' ` thanks for the help.`

Comment: @johndoe That should be writerow, sorry.